# massive memory leaks

Tags: init-file, autoload

I have a problem with memory leaks. Normally, I have only a few small org mode files loaded, and maybe a few odd yaml or Python files, less than 20 altogether). Over time, emacs keeps eating memory like there is no tomorrow, and after a few days, it accumulates several gigabytes more than at starting time. As a result, the machine starts swapping heavily. As much as I like emacs, this is untenable. At starting time, I get these figures for memory consumption: 1189288 543936 (from 'ps'), which look ok. I am using emacs 28.2.

I have loaded a few extensions: Ivy, Projectile, LSP, Org-Mode, neotree, magit, and a few that should make things "nicer".

When the memory leak builds up, I don't see it in 'ps', but when I close emacs, I see system memory consumtion dropping by several gigabytes, often more than 10.

Do you have any tips about how I can debug this problem properly?

Comment: Those numbers are meaningless without more information. What exact command did you run to get them, and what columns were the numbers in? Can you reproduce the problem with `emacs -q`?

Comment: Does `M-x memory-report` give a clue?

Comment: @db48x I ran 'ps auwwx | grep emacs'. I have not reproduced the problem with 'emacs -q', which doesn't load any of my configuration, yet, but I doubt it's there.

Comment: @BramSchoenmakers I am not familiar with this command, but altogether, memory usage looks like less than 200MB, certainly not over 10GB, as it tends to grow over time with my only editing a few small yaml or python files in between.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you ran `ps -O rss,size,vsize,%mem -C emacs` and pasted in the entire output, including the column headers. But as @user29402 says, that doesn’t look like 10 gigabytes to me. Remember that the kernel caches files in memory too, and that this increases the performance of the machine without reducing the amount of memory that applications are allowed to use if they need it. How much memory does your machine have? How much is actually in use? Paste in the output of `free -h`, taken while the problem is happening.

Comment: If `ps` doesn't indicate that Emacs itself is using a lot of memory, perhaps it's an external process ran by Emacs that's the culprit? For example, an LSP server or a linter.

Comment: Good point - I am running lsp-server.